# Installing OpenLDAP on Centos 7: Missing mdb Database?

Tags: centos, centos7, openldap

I'm trying to install OpenLDAP on Centos 7 by following the instructions here:

```
http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/quickstart.html
```

Here is my `slapd.ldif` file, which is the same as the sample one except for the domain name (redacted here):

```
dn: olcDatabase=mdb,cn=config 
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig 
objectClass: olcMdbConfig 
olcDatabase: mdb 
OlcDbMaxSize: 1073741824 
olcSuffix: dc=redacted,dc=com 
olcRootDN: cn=Manager,dc=redacted,dc=com 
olcRootPW: secret 
olcDbDirectory: /usr/local/var/openldap-data 
olcDbIndex: objectClass eq
```

I'm running this command to initialize the database, which is the same as the provided command except for the folders (which were different on my machine).

```
slapadd -n 0 -F /etc/openldap/slapd.d -l /usr/share/openldap-servers/slapd.ldif
```

This gives the following error:

```
slapadd: could not add entry dn="cn=config" (line=1):
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I did note that the `/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config` folder doesn't have a database corresponding to mdb, so I'm not sure if I need to install that.

Comment: Does the `olcDbDirectory` that you're trying to use exist with the appropriate permissions? Under CentOS7 its more normal to use `/var/lib/ldap/` than ` /usr/local/var/openldap-data`.

Comment: It occurs to me that you may be taking the mad opproach of trying to compile and install OpenLDAP on CentOS7. You really shouldn't. I hope you are installing the standard package instead: `yum install openldap-servers`.

Comment: @84104 The directory exists and the permissions look correct. I just did a yum install.

Comment: Including the selinux ones? `drwx------. ldap ldap system_u:object_r:slapd_db_t:s0  /var/lib/ldap/`

Answer (score 0):

If you install the `openldap-servers` package on CentOS 7, you have already three databases and the default database back-end is not `mdb` but the deprecated `hdb`.

This shows the configured databases:

```
# ldapsearch -Y EXTERNAL -Q -H ldapi:/// -LLL -o ldif-wrap=no -b cn=config '(objectClass=olcDatabaseConfig)' ''
```

This is the output on CentOS 7:

```
dn: olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config

dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config

dn: olcDatabase={1}monitor,cn=config

dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
```

You can not create the configuration database, if it is already there.